# An inequality concerning integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Does the inequality 
$$\ 2 \cdot p_1^{k1} \cdot ... \cdot p_6^{k6} < (p_1^{(k1+1)} -1)/p_1-1  ...\cdot(p_6 ^{(k6+1)} - 1)/p_6-1$$ 
always holds for any odd prime $p_1, p_2, ...p_6$ ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Not necessarily. Try an odd multiple of $945$ with exactly $6$ distinct prime factors.

For more details, google *odd abundant number*.

Comment: Thank you so much its a big help

Comment: You are welcome. Note the general fact that ay multiple of an abundant number is abundant.